# Pygame, been having trouble with making a Menu screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have been have a lot of trouble with my summative project where you have to make a game in python using pygame. I am currently stuck with trying to make a menu screen for my game, the problem is I can't get my buttons to show up and after that how to change to my game map once they click start. I have been getting the type error "TypeError: button() takes from 6 to 7 positional arguments but 9 were given" if any of you could help that would mean a lot. thanks.

```
#army man man
import pygame
from pygame import *
from tkinter import *
import time
import random
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))

pygame.display.set_caption("Armymanman")

walkright = [pygame.image.load('walk1.png'),pygame.image.load('walk2.png'),pygame.image.load('walk3.png'),pygame.image.load('walk4.png'),pygame.image.load('walk5.png'),pygame.image.load('walk6.png'),pygame.image.load('walk7.png'),pygame.image.load('walk8.png'),pygame.image.load('walk9.png')]
walkleft = [pygame.image.load('walk1L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk2L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk3L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk4L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk5L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk6L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk7L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk8L.png'),pygame.image.load('walk9L.png')]
backg = pygame.image.load('pythonbg.png')
#resize char image
char = pygame.image.load('stand.png')
char = pygame.transform.scale(char,(64,64))
x=0
y=720
w=1280
h=720
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
blue=(0,0,255)
green=(0,255,0)
white=(255,255,255)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#plays music does not work?
#def playmusic():
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(22050, -16, 2, 2048) # setup mixer
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('bgmusic.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

#playmusic()

##song=pygame.mixer.sound('bgmusic.ogg')
##
##song.play()




class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.move = 5
        self.isjump = False
##        self.isjump=0
        self.jumpcount = 10
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkcount = 0


    def draw(self,win):
        if self.walkcount + 1 >=27:
            self.walkcount = 0

        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkleft[self.walkcount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkcount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkright[self.walkcount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkcount += 1
        else:
            win.blit(char, (self.x,self.y))


def redrawwindow():
    win.blit(backg, (0,0))
    man.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

startsc=pygame.image.load('armymanbg.jpg')
startsc=pygame.transform.scale(startsc,[1280,720])
win.blit(startsc,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
DIS=1
def button(x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click= pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w>mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        global DIS
        global intro

        pygame.draw.rect(win,ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action!= None:
            if action=="START":
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                run= False
                DIS=2

            elif action=="EXIT":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif action=="Menu":
                DIS=1
            else:
                return True
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    text = pygame.font.SysFont('freesonsbold.ttf',25)
    win.blit(text.render("BECOME THE ARMYMANMAN!", True,(black)), (x+(w/3.1), y+(h/2.5)))
    win.blit(text.render("Start",True,(black)), (x+(w/3.1), y+(h/2.5)))
    win.blit(text.render("Exit",True,(black)), (x+(w/3.1), y+(h/2.5)))  

#MAIN LOOP
man = player(0, 656, 64, 64)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)
    if DIS==1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
        win.fill((0,0,0))
        button("START",400, 500, 150, 75,green,blue,"START")
        button("EXIT", 400,650,150,75,green,red,"EXIT" )
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()


        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT)and man.x < 1280 - man.width - man.move:
            man.x += man.move
            man.right = True
            man.left = False
        elif (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT)and man.x > man.move:
            man.x -= man.move
            man.left = True
            man.right = False
        else:
            man.right= False
            man.left = False
            man.walkcount = 0








if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE):
    man.isjump = True
    man.right = False
    man.left = False
    man.walkcount = 0
else:
    if(man.isjump==True):
        if man.jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpcount < 0:
                 neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpcount ** 2) *0.5 * neg
            man.jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            man.isjump = False
            man.jumpcount = 10

    redrawwindow()
print(man.y)


pygame.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you really shouldn't do `from pygame import *`, as it will pollute your namespace with lots of stuff you don't want, `from pygame.locals import *` is more normal. The `TypeError` you mention is due to you giving `button()` too many parameters. You can see that it takes six or seven parameters when you define it (`def button(x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):`). When you call it you try to pass too many (`button("START",400, 500, 150, 75,green,blue,"START")`). I think the initial `"START"` parameter is the excess. Here are some other things I've noticed:

- `if(man.isjump==True):` can be replaced with `if man.isjump:`. There seem to be lots of similar excess brackets. You do not need them around comparisons unless it's something like `if x and (a or b)`, where it makes a difference. You also do not need them around most function parameters. This button-drawing lines with `(black)` are an example of this.
- The final `pygame.quit` is unnecessary and will not work anyway (*if* you needed it, which you don't, it would be `pygame.quit()`.
- All of your buttons are drawn in the same place; try changing the draw coordinates to be different
- Your whitespace is strange. As a general rule, do not have trailing whitespace at the end of lines or a gap of more than two blank lines.
- In this line (`pygame.draw.rect(window, ic, (x,y,w,h))`), you draw to `window` instead of `win`, which breaks it.
- The whole section of code after the huge whitespace glob (excluding `pygame.quit`, which should be removed) needs to be indented.
- `if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT)` can be replaced with `if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]` and similar for left. These, along with `redrawwindow()` should be outside of the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop.